# What is the least amount of money a person can get if each person gets the average of the people next to them

Tags: algebra-precalculus

5 people sit around a circular table.We want to divide(Possibly unequally) $100 so each person get the average of the amount that the people to his/her right and left got.Whats the least amount of money one can get?
I tried to write each person’s money as the sum of the other people but I don’t know what to do from here.

Comment: With the given assumption, can you find a single configuration (other than $20$ each) that works?

Comment: Hint:  suppose the distribution is uneven and consider one of the people who has the most money, $X$.  How much money does each of that person's neighbors have?

Comment: @lulu Very good way of looking at it; pretty obvious that a person with the least amount of money will have people either side with more money hence violating a condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phil's argument is from pure logic, here is one based on arithmetic.

Call 5 people in order $a,b,c,d,e$ then $b = (a+c)/2$ and $e = (a+d)/2$ and we are left with $a,c,d$ to create the system. Imposing the conditions on them yields
$$
d = \frac{c + \frac{a+d}{2}}{2} \iff 3d = 2c+a\\
c = \frac{d + \frac{a+c}{2}}{2} \iff 3c = 2d+a\\
a = \frac{\frac{a+c}{2} + \frac{a+d}{2}}{2} \iff 2a = c+d\\
$$
which implies the set of equations
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -3 \\
1 & -3 & 2 \\
2 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}a \\ c \\ d\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
Subtracting the second from the first yields $5c-5d=0 \iff c=d$ and using that in the last one yields $a=c=d$. Hence, $b = (a+c)/2 = a = (a+d)/2 = e$, and all must have the same amount.